# How to replace eleventh character to "..."

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a long text in my div. I wish it only shows the ten characters then the rest of the content is replaced by `...`.

```
<div id="name">wahahahahahahahahahahaha</div>
```

In Jquery

```
$("div#name").text(function(index, currentText) {
    return currentText.substr(0, 10);
});
```

This jQuery worked and the long text stop until tenth.

Comment: why not just use plain css with text-overflow: ellipsis. using jquery for this is just overkill. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: @unikorn I tried it doesn't work in my code

Comment: @TheSmile Overflow must be different from visible. Should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add condition to check if text is more than 10 chars.

```
$("div#name").text(function(index, currentText) {   
    var newText = currentText.substr(0, 10);
    if(currentText.length > 10)
       newText += "...";

    return newText ;
});
```

Comment: Thanks u so much !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I will tick this answer later ... Thanks again !